# Bootstrap Affixed but scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

In bootstrap how can I make an affixed list so that it can be scrolled when it exceeds the page?

I put `overflow:scroll` on the parent `div` but it doesn't work (and  `overflow:scroll` on the `ul` itself doesn't work either)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Which browser do you use?

Comment: hi drmariod, thx for the answer. look this sidebar on that page http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix   , what happens if its a long sidebar? we must use scroll for the sidebar. im trying to do this. im using firefox at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `css`:

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Visit http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix for documentation

Comment: although the page you gave doesnt say something like this :P

Comment: @Markonato I know it doesn't :) added just for reference